# Method name must be a string error in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im getting this error when try to insert data into databse in laravel 5.2.
Check out through this code and find what i did as error

Controller.php

```
 public function store(Request $request){
    $this->$request([
     'title'=>'required',
      'description' => 'required'
        ]);
    Item::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('itemCRUD.index')
    ->with('success', 'Item created Successfully');
 }
```

create.php (short code)

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'itemCRUD.store','method'=>'POST')) !!}


            {!! Form::text('title', null, array('placeholder' => 'Title','class' => 'form-control')) !!}


            {!! Form::textarea('description', null, array('placeholder' => 'Description','class' => 'form-control','style'=>'height:100px')) !!}

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

please help me to find out the error

Comment: Yeah that works...thanks fr your needy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$this->$request([
    'title'=>'required',
    'description' => 'required'
]);
```

to

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title'=>'required',
    'description' => 'required'
]);
```

Hope this helps!